# DBMS To Load multiple types of dump files

Tags: migration

I just want to know if there's a DBMS for Linux that I can use to restore dump files from various other DBMS's, for example MySQL, PostgresSQL, SQL Server, etc.

I am in the task of migrating data from various DBMS's and I'm wondering if instead of using Wine for installing MSSQL, I can just install one DB to load/restore dump files and view its data and probably proceed with migration as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do [not use Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11312) to run SQL Server! SQL Server runs on Linux now - so
   if it's not a production instance, maybe you can use the developer
   edition (caveat: IANAL - check Microsoft's licencing for your case)
2. Since you're on Linux, you can use tools like sed, awk and grep
   which can be quite powerful for this sort of operation.
3. There are any number of RDBMS-X_2_RDBMS-Y scripts out there. A quick Google of [migrate from mysql to postgresql](https://www.google.com/search?q=migrate%20from%20mysql%20to%20postgresql&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab) gives, for example, [this page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL), where there is a plethora of tools both commercial and Open Source.

Finally, a **big** word of warning. My experience with doing this sort of task has shown me that none of the tools are perfect (far from it!). Apart from differences even in basic SQL datatypes (some custom and/or user defined) and syntax (even for relatively simple statements), you then have the **insurmountable** problem of "translating" `STORED PROCEDURE`s, `TRIGGER`s and `FUNCTION`s, where you really are off the reservation when it comes to tools!

Given the current state of technology, it is just **not possible** to just put the code from one server through a script and have the code for another drop out the end! There is an attempt to harmonise these through an ISO standard called [`Persistent Stored Modules`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/PSM). It is my belief that currently, vendors have too much invested in their own languages and approaches to want to (or be forced to) change anytime soon (think pension! :-) )!

The only way to do this is to have a programmer (skill level depending on the magnitude and difficulty of the migration/translation) do this "by hand" - i.e. building scripts that can cope with DDL and DML. In my experience, it is relatively easy to use sed and/or awk for this work and construct a pipeline of mini-scripts like, for example:

```
sed -i 's/NUMBER/DECIMAL/g' my_dump_file.sql
```

and for that to be satisfactory.

In order to do the `STORED PROCEDURE`s, `TRIGGER`s and `FUNCTION`s, you'll need a competent, experienced programmer who knows both systems reasonably well.